Limit of sequence of discrete measures is discrete
Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider a sequence of discrete probability measures $\mu_n := \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_{i,n}}$, where the points $x_{1,n},\ldots, x_{N,n} \in\mathbb{R}^{d}$. By weak-* compactness, we know that there is a finite Borel measure $\mu$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)\le 1$ such that (passing to a subsequence if necessary) $\mu_n \rightharpoonup \mu$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Question. Suppose we know that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^d)=1$. Is it then true that there exist points $x_1,\ldots,x_N\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$\mu = \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\delta_{x_i}$?

My suspicion is yes for reasons as follows.
First, there exists $R>0$ such that $\sup_{n,i} |x_{n,i}| \le R$.  Otherwise, $\mu(\mathbb{R}^{d})<1$. I'm a little iffy on this point, but I think it follows from $\mu$ being Radon, so given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $R>0$ such that $\mu(B_R)>1-\epsilon$. If there are infinitely many $x_{n,i}$ outside $B_R$, then for such $n$, $\mu_n(B_R) \le 1-\frac{1}{N}<1-\epsilon$, if we appropriately choose $\epsilon$.
Then by Heine-Borel, there exist points $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ such that (passing to a subsequence if necessary), $x_{n,i}\rightarrow x_i$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for each $i$. I claim that $\mu = \nu:=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_i}$. Indeed, given any $\varepsilon>0$, we may find a continuous function $\varphi_\varepsilon$ which is identically $1$ on $B(x_i,\varepsilon/2)$ and zero outside $B(x_i,\varepsilon)$. Hence, for all $n$ sufficiently large,
$$\int \varphi_\varepsilon d\mu_n = \frac{1}{N}|\{j: x_j = x_i\}| = \int \varphi_{\varepsilon} d\nu.$$
By applying this argument for each distinct point $x_1^*,\ldots,x_{N^*}^*$ in $\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$. Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $\mu(\{x_1^*,\ldots,x_{N^*}^*\}) = 1$. Thus, $\mu =\nu = \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_i}$.

Yes.
We prove this without the assumption that the limit is a probability measure.
By assumption of the weak convergence, for  every $f \in C_c$ (compactly supported continuous functions) we have
$$  \int f d \mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f d\mu_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_{n,i}).$$
Let $I$ be the subset of indices satisfying $\{x_{n,i}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is bounded. Pick a subsequence $(n_k)$ with the following properties:

For all $i\in I$ $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k,i} = x_i$.
For all $i \not \in I$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} |x_{n_k,i}|=\infty$.

It follows that for a fixed $f\in C_c$,
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} f(x_{n_k,i}) = \begin{cases} f (x_i) & i \in I \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and so
$$ (*)\quad \int f d \mu = \lim_{k\to\infty} \int f d\mu_{n_k} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_{n_k,i}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i\in I} f(x_i).$$
This allows to identify $\mu$ as $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i\in I} \delta_{x_i}$. If this is clear, we can stop here. Otherwise, let's continue.
By representing the constant function ${\bf 1}$ as a pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of $C_c$ functions, we have from $(*)$ (and monotone convergence) that $\mu(\mathbb R^d) = \frac{|I|}{N}$ (and which is $\le 1$).
Now let $A$ be any Borel set. By approximating the indicator of $\{x_i:i\in\mathbb N\}$ as a pointwise limit of a decreasing sequence of functions in $C_c$, we have from $(*)$ (and dominated convergence) that
$$ \mu(A \cap \{x_i:i\in I\}) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in I} \delta_{x_i}(A).$$
And so:

On the one hand,
$$\mu(A) \ge \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in I} \delta_{x_i}(A).$$
On the other hand, applying the above inequality to $A^c$ we obtain
$$\mu(A) = \mu(\mathbb R^d) - \mu(A^c)\le  \frac{|I|}{N} -  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in I} \delta_{x_i}(A^c) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i\in I} \delta_i(A).$$

And therefore
$$ \mu(A) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i\in I} \delta_{x_i}(A).$$
